# change raspberry pi date from php

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec, raspberry-pi2

I have a problem trying change date in rpi from php. 
If I write:

```
shell_exec('sudo date --set="15 NOV 2015 12:43:10"');
```

I don't get any feedback, output is `""`, but if I execute

```
shell_exec('date --set="15 NOV 2015 12:43:10"');
```

I recived

```
15 NOV 2015 12:43:10
```

as output but nothing change in rpi

I added www-data to sudoers with visudo command, and add

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but it didn't worked.

I've tried

```
chmod 777 /bin/date,
```

nothing.. I try make .sh file with command and run with and without sudo.. same result.

Any idea? Thanks to all!

PS.Sorry for my english

Comment: I solved my problem... after add to sudo group with command "adduser www-data sudo" and re-execute my first intuitive cmd sudo date --set... runs ok!!

Comment: Allowing ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL will be a big security hole if you put www-data in that group. That means the web server can run any root command!

Comment: I known, thanks... I tried this because nothing runs, finaly I resolved my problem with simple adduser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem... after add to sudo group with command `adduser www-data sudo` and re-execute my first intuitive cmd `sudo date --set`... runs ok!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sys_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2015-12-02"));
$sys_time ="08:00:00";
$sys_datetime = $sys_date." ".$sys_time;
$sys_datetime =strtotime($sys_datetime);
$date = gmdate('D M d H:i:s e Y', $sys_datetime);
shell_exec("sudo date -s \"$date\"");
?>
```

works for me..........